# Two way binding not working on primitive object with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In angular 2, I try to bind a string component property to an input directive parameter.
It looks like that the two way binding doesn't work with primitive property even though I use "banana in a box".

Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: "pairs-result",
  template: `
  <ul class="search-list">
    <li [(rowHover)]="showDetail">{{showDetail}}<pair-row></pair-row></li>
  </ul>
  `,
  directives: [HoverDirective]
})
export class PairsComponent {
  public showDetail: string = "initial value";
}
```

Directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[rowHover]'
})
export class HoverDirective {
  @Input('rowHover') hover: any;
  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
     this.hover = "mouse enter";
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
     this.hover = "mouse leave";
  }
}
```

[Code with Primitive not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJQcweONgz4eTDcennHe?p=preview)

But, if I change "hover" string property to an object property, it works.

[Code with Object works](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9tAyii6REoPAge2Z9he?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you using object, it is not binding but rather change detection.

You need to create `@Output` property with type `EventEmitter` and name `rowHoverChange`, and manually emit new values.

See how binding is implemented [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yiASwzr7MNTQnrQCnUQX?p=preview)

Comment: Actually, in my project I use EventEmitter, but I forgot to add "Change" word after my rowHover eventEmitter property. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Using primitives:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rowHover]'
})
export class HoverDirective {

  @Input('rowHover') hover: any;
  @Output() rowHoverChange = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.hover = "mouse enter";
    this.rowHoverChange.emit(this.hover);
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.hover = "mouse leave";
    this.rowHoverChange.emit(this.hover);
  }
}
```